# lxdbr0 and host machine source based routing

Tags: iptables, lxd

I have fairly regular LXD setup (version 3.0.3) with the default bridge interface lxdbr0 on Ubuntu 18.04.2.

On the other hand my host machines network is not the most regular. I have two bridges (br0 and br1), connected via two bonds to four interfaces (2 interfaces per bond, 1 bond per bridge).

Because I had hard time getting regular routing working properly I am using separate routing tables per bridge. I needed to get the requests and replies use the same egress path as ingress.

Now the issue is that I can ping everything and everywhere (host does IP masquerade) except hosts that are in the same sub net as br0 and br1 and as my forward proxy is in the same sub net as br1 I have problem. Host default route is also on br1.

The rules and routes for host machine are:

```
user@host:~$ ip route show
default via 10.10.50.254 dev br1 proto static
10.146.233.0/24 dev lxdbr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.146.233.1
10.10.99.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.99.1
10.10.50.0/24 dev br1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.50.1

user@host:~$ ip route show table 99
default via 10.10.99.254 dev br0 proto static

user@host:~$ ip rule show table 99
0:      from 10.10.99.0/24 lookup 99

user@host:~$ ip route show table 50
default via 10.10.50.254 dev br1 proto static

user@host:~$ ip rule show table 50
0:      from 10.10.50.0/24 lookup 50
```

The relevant netplan config as follows:

```
...
bridges:
    br0:
      addresses: [10.10.99.1/24]
      interfaces: [bond1]
      routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 10.10.99.254
        table: 99
      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.10.99.0/24
        table: 99
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 0
    br1:
      addresses: [10.10.50.1/24]
      gateway4: 10.10.50.254
      interfaces: [bond0]
      routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 10.10.50.254
        table: 50
      routing-policy:
      - from: 10.10.50.0/24
        table: 50
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 0
```

The only IPTABLES rules are generated by LXD

```
user@host:~$ sudo iptables -L -nv
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 828 packets, 62176 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  lxdbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
   16  1064 ACCEPT     udp  --  lxdbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
    2   658 ACCEPT     udp  --  lxdbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    7   588 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lxdbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
    7   588 ACCEPT     all  --  lxdbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 540 packets, 69728 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      lxdbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:53 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
   16  1020 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      lxdbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
    2   680 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      lxdbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
```

NAT rules are

```
user@host:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -nv
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1649 packets, 66895 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 9 packets, 899 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 927 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 927 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    3   252 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       10.146.233.0/24     !10.146.233.0/24      /* generated for LXD network lxdbr0 */
```

if I ping non br0 or br1 subnet addresses I can see requests and replies on br1, lxdbr0 and veth interfaces. If I ping br0 or br1 addresses I see only requests on lxdbr0 and veth interfaces. No traffic on br1 nor replies on any of the before mentioned interfaces.

and finally my interfaces configuration with omitted eth, lo and bond interfaces:

```
user@host:~$ ip a
7: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ee:f1:6a:84:6f:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.50.1/24 brd 10.10.50.255 scope global br1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ce:13:19:08:56:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.99.1/24 brd 10.10.99.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
22: lxdbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:cb:12:0f:9f:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.146.233.1/24 scope global lxdbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::70f5:3eff:feac:2ae6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
26: vethANRBKX@if25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master lxdbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:cb:12:0f:9f:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::fccb:12ff:fe0f:9fd7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My desired outcome would be to restrict NAT on 10.10.50.254 and 10.10.99.254 and access internet from the containers through my proxy in br1 sub network. I probably need to do something with my routing/policy rules or iptables or configure the lxdbr0 differently, but I seem to be stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the directly connected routes into your additional routing tables. In the current configuration, when you ping the addresses of the bridge interfaces, replies are routed through gateways (`10.10.50.254` and `10.10.99.254`) to outside.

You can verify the routing with commands:

- `ip route get 10.146.233.2 from 10.10.50.1`
- `ip route get 10.146.233.2 from 10.10.99.1`

You will see the actual routes and maybe will be a little confused.

So, your routing tables should be look like:

```
user@host:~$ ip route show table 50
default via 10.10.50.254 dev br1 proto static
10.146.233.0/24 dev lxdbr0 proto static scope link src 10.146.233.1
10.10.99.0/24 dev br0 proto static scope link src 10.10.99.1
10.10.50.0/24 dev br1 proto static scope link src 10.10.50.1

user@host:~$ ip route show table 99
default via 10.10.99.254 dev br0 proto static
10.146.233.0/24 dev lxdbr0 proto static scope link src 10.146.233.1
10.10.99.0/24 dev br0 proto static scope link src 10.10.99.1
10.10.50.0/24 dev br1 proto static scope link src 10.10.50.1
```